# Why iterate over the parts in a multipart email in javamail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I was looking at that `javamail` [faqs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody), I was looking at this snippet which is supposed to extract the body of the email:

```
    private boolean textIsHtml = false;

    /**
     * Return the primary text content of the message.
     */
    private String getText(Part p) throws
                MessagingException, IOException {
        if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
            String s = (String)p.getContent();
            textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
            return s;
        }

        if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
            // prefer html text over plain text
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
            String text = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                    if (text == null)
                        text = getText(bp);
                    continue;
                } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                    String s = getText(bp);
                    if (s != null)
                        return s;
                } else {
                    return getText(bp);
                }
            }
            return text;
        } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
            Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
                if (s != null)
                    return s;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Now the code can be refactored to the following version which is basically less lines of code:

```
    private static String getText(Part message) {
        String text = null;

        try {
            if (message.isMimeType("text/*")) {
                text = (String) message.getContent();
            }

            if (message.isMimeType("multipart/alternative") || message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                Part bodyPart       = multiPart.getBodyPart(multiPart.getCount() - 1);
                text                = getText(bodyPart);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return text;
    }
```

My question is, why the old code looping through the parts for both `multipart/alternative` and `multipart/*` messages? Am I missing something here?

Update:

Just saw Jon's comment, I have a further question, is there any scenario where my version of the code will break?

Comment: Your code always decides to use the final alternative - the original code prefers the text/html version over the text/plain version, exactly as the comment says.

Comment: @JonSkeet Would there be any particular scenario where my version of the code will break / won't work?

Comment: Well it depends on what you mean by "work". If the text/html part is followed by the text/plan part, your code will give a different result which may give a worse experience...

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are many Multipart types and they all need to handled uniquely:

Mixed Subtype

The "mixed" subtype of "multipart" is intended for use when the body
   parts are independent and need to be bundled in a particular order.
   Any "multipart" subtypes that an implementation does not recognize
   must be treated as being of subtype "mixed".

Alternative Subtype

The "multipart/alternative" type is syntactically identical to
   "multipart/mixed", but the semantics are different.  In particular,
   each of the body parts is an "alternative" version of the same
   information.

Systems should recognize that the content of the various parts are interchangeable.  Systems should choose the "best" type based on the local environment and references, in some cases even through user interaction.  As with "multipart/mixed", the order of body parts is significant.  In this case, the alternatives appear in an order of increasing faithfulness to the original content.

In general, the best choice is the LAST part of a type supported by the recipient system's local environment.

"Multipart/alternative" may be used, for example, to send a message
   in a fancy text format in such a way that it can easily be displayed
   anywhere:

```
 From: Nathaniel Borenstein <nsb@bellcore.com>
 To: Ned Freed <ned@innosoft.com>
 Date: Mon, 22 Mar 1993 09:41:09 -0800 (PST)
 Subject: Formatted text mail
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=boundary42

 --boundary42
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

   ... plain text version of message goes here ...

 --boundary42
 Content-Type: text/enriched

   ... RFC 1896 text/enriched version of same message
       goes here ...

 --boundary42
 Content-Type: application/x-whatever

   ... fanciest version of same message goes here ...

 --boundary42--
```

In this example, users whose mail systems understood the
   "application/x-whatever" format would see only the fancy version,
   while other users would see only the enriched or plain text version,
   depending on the capabilities of their system.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't "work" (whatever that means to you) with a multipart/mixed message where the last attachment is of type text/*.  Yes, attachments can be of type text/*.